# Messages present in batch gets lost when producer goes down

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

For example there is a source which generates high volume data at the rate of 10,000 records per second and kafka producer usually stores them into in-memory buffer and then sends it to the topic and before publishing the records, producer goes down. Hence records present in the buffer are lost.

Please suggest any config parameters to prevent this .
 i have used these config parameters:

```
acks = 1
batch.size = 160000
buffer.memory = 33554432

request.timeout.ms = 30000
retries = 2147483647
```

Answer (score 0):

```
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1
```

Comment: Producer can only guarantee no data loss after a successful `flush()` call or when the send callback or future indicate successful write.

Comment: Is there provision if the producer crashes at some point as usual the data present in the buffer will get lost .
So there any way to minimize that loss or either retransmit that lost data

Comment: You can flush() often. You can somehow keep track of the callback/Futures confirmations. However it is a balance between throughput and crash safety. I found another parameter... There is also the `block.on.buffer.full=true`parameter for you to set.

Comment: kafka documentation says block.on.buffer.full=true producer config has been removed as i am using kafka 1.0 .